# How to split a string separating multiple names with a separator python

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, title

[image: Attachment]
How to split columns song feat artist and join to title song

column name Artist, Title, Artist_followers

Ed Sheeran - Cardi B - Camila Cabello - Cheat   south of the  71783101

Ed Sheeran - Chris Stapleton - Bruno Mars       blow          71783101

output

Ed Sheeran  What do i do feat Cardi B & Camila Cabello & Cheat 71783101

Ed Sheeran  blow feat Chris Stapleton & Bruno Mars             71783101

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['artist'] = df['artist'].str.split('-')
df = df.explode('artist').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then You can just use the +.

```
df['artist'] + '_' + df['title']
```

I don't know the exact names for the columns since there are no present in the question

Comment: i need split name artist from Ed Sheeran - Cardi B - Camila Cabello - Cheat, only first person name Ed Sheeran after separator - is name feat artist after that add to title